# What sort of Index for 'AND' columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table to store people and want to select where the person is not marked as "deleted". I have a clustered primary key on the ID column  (`PersonID`).

The 'Deleted' column is a `DATETIME`, nullable, and is populated when deleted.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Person
WHERE PersonID = 100
AND Deleted IS NULL
```

This table can grow to around 40,000 people.
Should I have an index that covers the Deleted flag as well?

I may also query things like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Task t
INNER JOIN Person p
    ON p.PersonID = t.PersonID
    AND p.Deleted IS NULL
WHERE t.TaskTypeId = 5
AND t.Deleted IS NULL
```

Task table estimate is about 1.5 million rows.

I think I need one that covers both the pk and the deleted flag on both tables? i.e. on `(Task.TaskId, Task.Deleted)` and `(Person.PersonID, Person.Deleted)`?

Reasons for me investigating an index rethink, is due to a number of deadlock occurring in complex procedures. I'd like to reduce the number of rows locked on selects/writes/updates, as well as get a performance gain.

Comment: Good way - look at query execution plan. Sometimes, SQL Server gives very good recomendations about creating indexes based on his statistics. So, you can just find missing indexes.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan
 http://sqlperformance.com/2013/06/t-sql-queries/missing-index

Comment: An important metric is the stats and distribution of `deleted` columns. How many `deleted IS NULL` records do you have in each of your tables. If you always search for `deleted is null`, can can create a filtered index with this filter. Other than that, Do you query your deleted records? Do you need your deleted records to remain in the same table table. can it be moved to an archive table. these are some of the things you can consider.

Comment: Thanks @ughai - All queries have a 'Deleted IS NULL' check, including JOINS to that table. At the moment, 97% of the records are NULL (i.e. Not deleted). We never query 'WHERE Deleted IS NOT NULL'. I'm going to read what a 'filtered index' is, as that seems to be something useful.

Comment: Why is `PersonID` not clustered? You wouldn't need the indices if it were. In any case, 40 thousand rows is still in the realm when the engine might still decide not to use the index anyway - depending on the size of your row, of course. The second query is the more important one - you should focus on the filter that eliminates the most rows; it's not obvious what that is here.

Comment: My error, sorry. The PK on Person (PersonID) is indeed a clustered index. I'll edit that error.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, the fastest querying might well be using a filtered index. In this `Deleted` column whose type is `DATETIME` and nullable, you could try something like this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Filtered_Deleted_Index
ON dbo.Person(Deleted)
WHERE Deleted IS NOT NULL
```

This will get you the smallest valid set in both use cases you listed above (for querying `dbo.Person` and also joining with `Tasks`).

Comment: Since the I doubt your index which help much for this query(apart from the filter that is) since your primary index column is `Deleted` column and not on `PersonID` which is part of the join.

Comment: Completely agree with ughai, another point is selectivity of deleted column is very low and does not cover all column which OP required

Comment: Actually, this filtered index cannot help at all to find records where `Deleted IS NULL` when the index only track records where `Deleted IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Andreas, the filter can be adjusted to have IS NOT NULL or IS NULL based on data profile, which we don't know precisely. But the idea is to have a filtered index.

Comment: @ughai, this index does not replace other indexes, the pk, or the clustered index that OP may have. This index is an additional one that will serve just those two use cases the OP wanted. I can see your doubts when you confuse a filtered index with primary index.

Comment: By primary i mean the first index key in your index which is deleted. Once a filter is already applied there is no need to have a delete index key. You need to have personid in the index key to help facilitate the join.

Comment: @ughai my filtered index is not for the join but for filtering the fastest for both use cases, one of which does not use join.

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is (generally speaking) sound - an index that contains all columns needed for the query is called a *covering index*, which in this case would require:

```
CREATE INDEX Person_PersonID_Deleted ON Person(PersonID, Deleted);
```

You are unlikely to get much performance benefit on index lookup by adding the `Deleted` column, since searching for `null` is (usually) ignored, but having these indexes means that accessing the table can be bypassed entirely for `Person`.

You could also try creating:

```
CREATE INDEX Task_TaskTypeId_Deleted ON Task(TaskTypeId, Deleted);
```

which will avoid accessing `Task` rows that are marked as "deleted", and `Task` would then only accessed for non-deleted rows. However, if most of your `Tasks` are *not* deleted, I wouldn't bother with this index.

It's worth trying out various combinations of index(es) to see which combination gives the best result.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian - Would I also have one on PersonID only? Or would the covering index be suitable (With PersonID, Deleted)?

Comment: You would definitely keep the primary key, which is implicitly backed by an index, on PersonID only, to enforce the uniqueness of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Since the primary key is `PersonID`, adding another index with extra columns after PersonID will not improve the "selectability" of the index, although is may prevent the need to lookup the record by rowid for filtering on `deleted`. With only 3% records filtered, that's nothing, so don't create another index on `Person`.

As for the `Task` table, it very much depends on the selectability of `TaskTypeId = 5 AND Deleted IS NULL`, i.e. how many records match the criteria. In general, a sequential search (full table scan) is faster than an index scan with row lookup if more than 20% of the records are selected. For very larger tables where the data is very distributed (e.g. physically every 10th record is selected), the performance threshold is below 10%.

So, if more than 10-20% of Task records are type 5, and only 3% of records are deleted, no index will improve performance, because the fastest access plan is likely a merge join of two full table scans.

Comment: It's interesting that you mentioned 'Lockup'. The issue that's caused our re-think of indexing is due to a number of deadlocks occurring. So we're attempting to reduce the number of rows locked, as well as speed.

Comment: If you're having deadlock issues, you might want to consider turning snapshot mode on, since that eliminates the need for queries to obtain record locks.

Comment: In general, a sequential search (full table scan) is faster than an index scan with row lookup if more than 20% of the records are selected. 
"DO you mean by index seek with row/key lookup"

Comment: @Neeraj Yes, index scan/seek on the indexed columns with a nested loop to lookup the row by rowid (unclustered) or by key (clustered).